# How do I apply a stylesheet on page leave in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css

I'm new to asp.net and don't know if this is possible.

My goal is that if the client is leaving a certain page "current page" that a specific style sheet would be applied on a master-page (which would be for every other page on the site).

I would think it would be something like...

- Link to x page is fired from current page
- Current page code behind either sets a session or a request url
- x page (or master page) code behind reads the session object or the url
- "if" statement is fired and applies the style sheet

I should note- all the links on the current page are regular  links. I'd like to accomplish this without changing each link to an asp control.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET themes? Perhaps that is that what you want to toggle on the client instead... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykzx33wh.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you used the url /default.aspx?css=1 or whatever, then you can use something like

```
if request.querystring("css") = 1 then
Dim cssLink As New HtmlLink()
cssLink.Href = "~/styles.css"
cssLink.Attributes.Add("rel", "stylesheet")
cssLink.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css")
Header.Controls.Add(cssLink)
end if
```

I haven't tried this or anything but should be ok.

Similar if you use

```
session("css") = "1"
```

when you click the link..

```
if session("css") = 1 then...
```